# not iterable python (different integer values for assigned variable in loop and making them into one)

Tags: python

I was making a betting game and output results in `matplotlib`. Just couldn't find a solution to my problem. for the x variable - there are multiple funds values in the end of the simple game. I wish to do some calculations on them but they seem to output separately in the console.[100][120][80]

I can't seem to merge them into one as the value of funds is a "seperated" integer in each iteration of the program.

```
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def simple_bettor(funds,fraction,wager_count):
    def rollDice():
        roll = random.randint(1,2)
        if roll == 2:
            return True
        elif roll == 1:
            return False
    wX= [0]
    vY= [funds]
    no_of_bets = 1

    while no_of_bets <= wager_count:
        if rollDice() is False:
            funds -= fraction
            wX.append(no_of_bets)
            vY.append(funds)
        else:
            funds += fraction
            wX.append(no_of_bets)
            vY.append(funds)
        no_of_bets += 1
    if funds < 0:
        funds = 0
    # print('Funds:', value)
    plt.plot(wX,vY)
    x =[]
    x.append(funds)
    print(x)


iterations = 0
while iterations < 3:
    simple_bettor(100,10,10)
    iterations += 1

plt.ylabel('Account Value')
plt.xlabel('Number of Bets')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You've made a good start by posting complete, verifiable example.  I suspect that your issue doesn't relate specifically to `matplotlib` (which I don't have so I can't run your example).  And it definitely doesn't yet use pandas or numpy.  Please eliminate everything that's not crucial, to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Replacing `plt` with `print` calls, I get output, but I can't tell what it is you want the output to be and how it would differ from what I get.  Post the expected output.  I can't figure out what  you mean by "merge".  Do you want the printed values to be in a single list?

Comment: Sorry for that . Will make changes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish - does this work for you?

```
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def simple_bettor(funds,fraction,wager_count):
    def rollDice():
        roll = random.randint(1,2)
        if roll == 2:
            return True
        elif roll == 1:
            return False
    wX= [0]
    vY= [funds]
    no_of_bets = 1

    while no_of_bets <= wager_count:
        if rollDice() is False:
            funds -= fraction
            wX.append(no_of_bets)
            vY.append(funds)
        else:
            funds += fraction
            wX.append(no_of_bets)
            vY.append(funds)
        no_of_bets += 1
    if funds < 0:
        funds = 0
    # print('Funds:', value)
    plt.plot(wX,vY)
    return funds

iterations = 0
x =[]
while iterations < 3:
    x.append(simple_bettor(100,10,10))
    iterations += 1

print(x)

plt.ylabel('Account Value')
plt.xlabel('Number of Bets')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Awesome! 1) I added `return funds` to your function, so that its output can be used later; 2) I moved the initialisation (and `appends`) related to the list `x` outside of the function and around the `while` loop.

Comment: that's amazing, so you just return the variable "funds" and created a list x and appended the final values to it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help! Remember that you can accept the answer if it solved your problem